# Recovering earned Avatar items

Tags: xbox-360

I transferred my data from my HDD to my flash drive since I will be getting another console soon to replace the one that broke down a few years back. I will be using a flash drive as the primary storage.

When I transferred my data yesterday, the avatar items I unlocked by playing games like Halo: Reach and the ones I downloaded from the Marketplace as part of a pre-order bonus did not get transferred over and were corrupted when I tried to access them on my HDD after the transfer. I am pretty sure I can re-download the ones I got as a pre-order bonus, but how can I recover the ones I unlocked from games?

Comment: I assume you have an Xbox Live account. Did you recover it on the new box?

Comment: Yes, I did it today. I did not know if the avatar rewards would be there after I recovered my account. It looks like they are all there when I skimmed through.

Answer (score 1):

Re-download your Xbox Live account. To do this, sign in and select the "Download profile" tab. After you sign-in, go to the avatar editor and head to "Awards" gradually go through each game and apply/equip each item. If the selected item is not present or is damaged, the avatar editor will ask you to re-download them. For purchased items, go to:

*Settings> Account> Download history*

There, you will find a full list of your downloaded items. You can also get your avatar awards just by deleting the corrupt ones and inserting the game disk that they came from while signed-in. The game will detect that you have unlocked them, and save them to the HDD. Avatar award bins are stored *in* the game they are unlocked from. It's not the best or fastest option, but will suffice if you don't have an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Recover your Xbox Live account on the new box, and all your avatar awards should come with it.